# On the definition of principal Cartier divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In Liu's Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves, Definition 7.1.17, a few lines after the definition of principal Cartier divisor (as one in the image of $\Gamma (X,K_X^*) \to \Gamma (X,K_X^*/ \mathcal{O} _X^*)$), we read (for an arbitrary scheme $X$):

[A Cartier divisor] is principal if it can be represented by a system {$(X,f)$}.

I understand that this is only an "if" and not an "if and only if" in general. Am I right?
(if $X$ is *integral* or *affine noetherian* we have an "only if").